# is there any system call that blocks the memory

Tags: c, linux

i am newbie to c and Linux , In  my c program one.c, i have a variable x=10 stored at address some 0x34.now,i don't want any other process to access this memory location except that one.c.no other process should overwrite, or can access this location...is there any system call which supports this ?thank you in advance

Comment: I fear that you'll have to use shared memory for this. Memory protection, virtualization, paging... will prevent a process from accessing another process memory otherwise.

Comment: That's the default. Remember that Linux uses *virtual memory*. A memory address in one process doesn't have to the same in another process (even if the processes were created from the same executable). And unless they explicitly shares memory, then no other process should be able to access the memory of another process.

Comment: Unless you take action to permit another process to access the variable, it is unique to just the one process.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on your question? ***Why*** do you wonder? What is the *actual* problem you have?

Comment: None of what you are talking about makes any sense. As a C newbie you should not be worrying about processess or addresses or memory protection before you actually encounter a problem with any of these. If you have a problem with your C program, post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

That's precisely how operating systems with [memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection) work:

> The main purpose of memory protection is to prevent a process from
>   accessing memory that has not been allocated to it. This prevents a
>   bug or malware within a process from affecting other processes, or the
>   operating system itself. An attempt to access unowned memory results
>   in a hardware fault, called a segmentation fault or storage violation
>   exception, generally causing abnormal termination of the offending
>   process.

Virtually every general-purpose OS today uses memory protection, so you already have it.